# MobilePush Fence Entry & Fence Exit information

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

We need to send push notifications when a user enters/exits a location ***based on some conditions***. I have stumbled upon this [MobilePush products faq](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_FAQ_product.htm&type=5), where it is stated:

> **What kind of data are captured when the analytics flag is enabled?**
>
> The SDK captures these analytic events and sends them back to the
> Marketing Cloud. These flags are subject to change.
>
> Fence Entry:  Indicates that a device crossed into a geofence.
>
> Fence Exit:   Indicates that a device left a geofence.
>
> Time in Location:     Captures the amount of time a device is inside a geofence.

I believe analytics are enabled on the configuration file of the app using the analytics:true value.

**My questions are:**

How often is this data being sent to Marketing Cloud?

Any idea on how to get this data in Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analytics data is transmitted to the Marketing Cloud as the application goes into the background.

The Entry/Exit data can be seen in Push Reporting.

You know that Marketing Cloud offers messaging as a result of a fence entry/exit, correct?

Did you know that you can register a transition event listener? (ref. https://bit.ly/3lzXGPB)

Did you know that you can register a `should show message` listener? (ref. https://bit.ly/2PcfV1l)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Bill. I cant find Entry/Exit data anywhere (tried MobilePush Detail Extract Report, Push Message Summary Report, Push Message Detailed Report). No fields on the _PushAddress data views as well. Any idea on where to find this data?

Comment: It may take some correlation.  A "message" would be displayed as the result of an entry or exit.

Comment: Yeah but as mentioned in my question, we need to kind of log when a customer enters/exits an area so that we can send him a push notification based on some conditions (commercial pressure, how long he has been in that location,..) on Marketing Cloud :/

Comment: Then I suggest seeing the rest of my answer.  Implement one, or both, of those interfaces and work with an API integration to trigger the send.